# making dropdown in the very center of the page

Tags: php, html, css, styles

I wanna make the *dropdown list* to appear in the center of the page. How do I do that?

Code:

```
echo '<div class="dropCenter" align="center">';        
echo '<label><SELECT name="projectDropdown" id="projectDropdown" class="projectSelect">'.'<br>';
echo '<OPTION VALUE=" ">'."".'</OPTION>';

while($row = oci_fetch_array($compCuttingResult,OCI_ASSOC)) {
     $projectName = $row ['PROJECT_NAME'];
     echo "<OPTION VALUE='$projectName'>$projectName</OPTION>";
}

echo '</SELECT></label><br />';
```

Comment: Putting the massive markup errors aside (e.g. the `<select>` being within a `<label>`) your question appears to be asking about the element *positioning* on the page, which would be a CSS question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove all BR and LABEL tags from the HTML markup.
Next append a closind DIV tag at the end of the markup.

#### PHP Code

```
$html = null;
$html .= "<div class=\"dropCenter\">";
$html .= "<select id=\"projectDropDown\" name=\"projectDropDown\">";
$html .= "<option value=\"\"></option>";
while($row = oci_fetch_array($compCuttingResult,OCI_ASSOC)){
    $projectName = $row['PROJECT_NAME'];
    $html = sprintf("<option value=\"%s\">%s</option>", $projectName, $projectName);
}
$html .= "</select>";
$html .= "</div>";
print $html;
```

#### CSS Code

```
<style type="text/css">
    select.projectSelect{ width:280px; height:24px; margin:10px; }
    select.projectSelect option{line-height:24px;}
    div.dropCenter{ display:inline-block; position:absolute; width:300px; height:34px; margin-left:-150px; margin-top:-17px; background-color:#e0e0e0; border:1px solid #c0c0c0; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the style to the first div

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

This should put the div in center

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
margin:auto;

<div class="dropCenter" style= 'margin:auto;'>
```

also you will have to check what are the divs you have above this.  If there is no effect with above divs this would work fine.

External Inherited Style Sheets will also have an effect.